# Aplicar paleta de cores em imagem crua

Tags: python, c, imagem, processamento-de-imagens, cores

Eu tenho uma imagem em níveis de cinza e quero um algoritmo para aplicar uma paleta de cores a ela. Alguém possui referência de uma técnica de algoritmo utilizada ou algo do gênero? Não sou experiente com processamento digital de imagens. Se houver alguma biblioteca em C ou python que possa me ajudar a fazer tal aplicação ou aprender coisas novas no campo, também é de bastante utilidade.

Agradeço

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o [GIMP](http://gimp.org). Ele tem opções para isso direto nos menus de cor - mas se o uso interativo não for o suficiente para você,
o programa expõe centenas de chamadas a sua API interna (chamada "PDB" - "Procedural Data Base"), as ligações de Python e Scheme embutidas - então você pode facilmente fazer um script dentro do GIMP para abrir uma imagem, calcular um mapa de cores, e chamar `pdb.gimp_image_set_colormap`.

Essa é uma das opções. Outra é usar a `pillow` de Python - e acesso a pixels direto para colorir cada pixel - ,as existem outras vária sbibliotecas de imagem que te permitem criar isso diretamente também.